# Fast crytographically secure Pseudo-Random number generator in software

Tags: hash, stream-cipher, pseudo-random-generator, isaac

What are the methods for generating pseudo-random numbers in software? I have seen methods where people use SHA implementations from openssl to hash a random message as source of entropy, or using AES or Keccak. But I have done some experiments and found them quite slow. They take around more than 3 clock cycles in an intel 3.3GHz i5 processor to generate a random bit. Whereas pseudo-random generators like ISAAC are blazingly fast compared to other methods. Now my question is

1. Why don't people use ISAAC for their implementations?
2. Is ISAAC not secure enough for cryptographic applications?
3. What are the other methods available for fast pseudo random number generation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just like to remark that in the special (nevertheless practically not to be ignored) case of the communications of the common users where RSA is employed for encryption purposes, one needs to (ever) generate only two appropriate primes. In that case the efficiency issue of random number generation is evidently entirely irrevant and one should preferrably employ Maurer's algorithm of generation of provable primes (i.e. instead of statistically highly possibly primes).

Comment: @Mok-KongShen I fail to see how this has anything to do with the subject at hand; RSA is mentioned nowhere in the question. And sorry, but I dare to disagree with this. RSA key pair generation is often performed with high entropy random numbers, and it that case you may have issues with e.g. blocking RNG's. But instead of continuing the discussion on it, it would be nicer if you'd remove your comment.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: The first sentence of OP together with the beginning of his second sentence (via supplying an example) implies IMHO that he is highly concerned with the general efficiency issue of PRN generation on a computer. I was remarking that there is e.g. a (special) case of crypto applications where the efficiency issue of PRN generation is IMHO irrelevant. I don't yet clearly see why this remark is out of context here.

Answer (score 8):

> What are the methods for generating pseudo-random numbers in software?
>
> What are the other methods available for fast pseudo random number generation?

If you don't need to be able to repeat the stream of numbers, there is little reason not to use the methods provided by the operating system - namely, urandom on linux, and CryptGenRandom in Windows. The [RDRAND CPU instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) is another option, though it is often times combined with other sources of random number generation, as [not everyone trusts it completely](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/12/09/freebsd_abandoning_hardware_randomness/) (you can ignore this unless you are dead set on obtaining absolutely *secure* random numbers).

Otherwise, assuming a modern CPU with [AES-NI support](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/01/11/aes-ni-in-laymens-terms), nothing will likely be faster then utilizing AES in [CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29). There is no need to hash the output, this is just eating cycles for no statistical or security benefit.

> Why don't people use ISAAC for their implementations?

We can only conjecture at the motivations of others. Some reasons might include:

- ISAAC is not a hugely well known algorithm in the same tier as AES or salsa20

  - If they are not aware it's existence, they will not use it
- Their requirements may be satisfied with simpler/more commonly used algorithms
- *Secure* random numbers are not always required; Often times, numbers that look random enough work just fine.
- On the other hand, sometimes security is required, as well as conformance to a particular security standard. ISAAC is not a standardized (read: officially prescribed) algorithm for use as a PRNG by any official organizations i.e. NIST.

  - AES-CTR-DRBG *is* a standards compliant PRNG.

> Is ISAAC not secure enough for cryptographic applications?

[The jury appears to be out on this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15976/is-isaac-cipher-cryptographically-secure?noredirect=1&lq=1). There was a reason to prompt the author to design ISAAC+, so while there is no known attack that breaks it outright, it does provide less assurance then a thoroughly reviewed design such as AES or salsa20.

Comment: Also note that ISAAC is not NIST-approved as a DRBG and the other approved ones are just fine (especially AES_CTR_DRBG)

Comment: Also also note that ISAAC isn't a PRNG is it?  It's a steam cipher according to the the majority opinion here.

Comment: @PaulUszak A stream cipher is effectively equivalent to a PRNG - simply encrypt a block of all 0s (or a block of anything really, it does not matter). The resultant output is clearly a string of psuedo-random numbers. Additionally, ISAAC appears to be explicitly designed to be used as a PRNG, as was indicated in an [accepted answer to a question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42913/29554) you asked about the subject.

Comment: "Nothing will likely be faster then utilizing AES in CTR mode"  - well the RDRAND instruction exists and is much faster.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson The key part of that statement was "Otherwise, assuming a modern CPU with AES-NI support" - without this clarification, this statement would simply be incorrect, even without considering the existence of RDRAND. AES is far from the fastest cipher algorithm in the world when implemented in software. That being said, I can mention RDRAND next to urandom and friends in the answer.

Comment: My point was that even with NI, which all CPUs with RDRAND have afaik, the RDRAND instruction will result in randoms faster still.  OTOH, I realize that's off topic since RDRAND won't give you a PRNG like NI will and the topic is really PRING not RNG.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That runs contrary to my intuition: [If RDRAND is implemented using AES-CTR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26781934/3103584), how could it possibly be faster then AES-CTR, especially when it has to do other things as well? The question on that page also contains performance figures that indicate that RDRAND is not necessarily always the fastest option: according to that question, it apparently can be beaten by a mersenne twister on at least some CPUs. It seems like RDRAND is better as a TRNG, rather then a PRNG. (Learned a lot about it today!)

Comment: MT is not cryptographic.  I acknowledged rdrand does not a prng make.  Your intuition forgets all the savings and optimizations that can come from bundling operations in a single specialized instruction.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson According to the specs from Intel, RDRAND *does use* a PRNG underneath: *With respect to the RNG taxonomy discussed above, the DRNG follows the cascade construction RNG model, using a processor resident entropy source to repeatedly seed a hardware-implemented CSPRNG.* Actually it uses CBC-MAC for conditioning the TRNG and then the CTR_DRBG as seeded PRNG.

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion. I got to know a lot of things. Is there any sample code which uses AES in CTR mode using NI instructions. I want to verify speed.